# Mobilefirst 7.1 - How can I install App Center in development environment with eclipse.

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

How can I install App Center in development environment with eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Application Center has got nothing to do with Eclipse or any other "development environment". It is a stand-alone server that you upload application binary files to in order to distribute them in an enterprise. Please read the Application Center documentation...

Comment: I did went thought couple of documentation most of then suggest to install MFP with Installation Manager  App Center comes with it like [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/t_ov_server_install.html?lang=en).  The other documentation I followed was regarding Manually installing App Center like [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/c_manually_configuring_databases_for_ac.html?lang=en). But I dont have the WAR files mentioned in this doc.

Comment: If you are an IBM customer, you will be able to download them from the location that was provided to you.